# Error when doing "vagrant provision" with berkshelf

Tags: vagrant, berkshelf, vagrant-plugin

I am using Windows with *vagrant* and *chefdk* installed. I can successfully `vagrant up` a VM without problem. So my next thing to do is to add provisioning feature to it. I downloaded some cookbooks and created a `Berksfile` to solve the dependencies, however when I run `vagrant provision`, it shows me the following error:

```
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `mkdir': No such file or directory - K: (Errno::ENOENT)
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:245:in `fu_mkdir'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:219:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `reverse_each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:217:in `block in mkdir_p'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/fileutils.rb:203:in `mkdir_p'
    from C:/Users/victorwong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-4.0.3/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/load.rb:40:in `mkshelf'
    from C:/Users/victorwong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-4.0.3/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/load.rb:23:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/Users/victorwong/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/vagrant-berkshelf-4.0.3/lib/vagrant-berkshelf/action/check.rb:18:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_box.rb:56:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:214:in `action_raw'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:191:in `block in action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:516:in `lock'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:178:in `action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.7.2/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

It tells me it cannot `mkdir` on `K:` as it does not exist. It was the drive of an external drive which I disconnected right now. I have no idea why `K:` comes out here. This error does not appear when I do not enable `berkshelf`, so it might be related to `berkshelf`.

My Berksfile:

```
source "https://supermarket.getchef.com"

cookbook 'java', path: 'chef-script/cookbooks/java'
```

My Vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
# ...
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest
  config.berkshelf.enabled=true

  config.vm.provision "chef_solo" do |chef|
    chef.cookbooks_path = "chef-script/cookbooks"
    chef.add_recipe "java"
  end
end
```

So, 2 questions:

Q1. how can I force it to `C:` instead of `K:`;

Q2. why does it point to `K:` by default?

Comment: run ```berks install```, ```vagrant destroy```, ```vagrant up``` and put the full log and your Berksfile and Vagrantfile.

Comment: @acfreitas, I have attached both files. I ran `berks install` and it returns the same error. If I `vagrant destroy` then `vagrant up`, same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the reason behind, hope someone would feel useful. It is actually very simple. The `K:` comes from the environmental variables `HOMEDRIVE`.

By typing command in CMD of Windows

```
SET
```

A list of runtime environmental variables comes out. If there is something look like this

```
HOMEDRIVE=K:
```

or whatever weird drive letter, then bingo! Now to change the value, simply

```
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
```

Then things work like a charm.

Still I have no idea who and when it set this runtime variable. But anyway it solved my problem.